# Left and right padding bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code

```
<div class="col-md-12 pt-5 let-top">
    <h1>A</h1>
</div>
```

On small and xs screen I want to add a padding on the left and on the right. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-12 px-<your number> px-sm-<your number> px-md-0">
```

In this way, under `MD` your `div` will have a custom padding on the left and the right, but it will be removed when you reach the `MD breakpoint`.

Of course "px" means the paddings on both sides will be the same, if you want different padding then use the `pl` and `pr` classes.

Please remember that, in the bootsrap config file there is already a specified gutter on the `col` class which means every `col` will have a **default paddings** on the sides. You can overwrite it if you config the variables in the file.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap 4 do not have `xs` size so you can't use `px-xs-3` (`px` means both sides)

The trick is:

1. add padding to all sizes include size under `sm` : `<div class="px-3">`
2. remove the padding from `sm` and up `<div class="px-3 px-sm-0">`

[See code example](https://jsfiddle.net/kueLfg4o/1/)

Answer (score 0):

dedicate one column size to padding:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-10 offset-xs-1  pt-5 let-top">
           <h1>A</h1>
</div>
```